# WebViewDatabase NullPointerException

Tags: android

I've done many many tests on my app. Google market show me this error. By "OTHER" device. Which kind of device is "OTHER"? and which cause has created error?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getCacheTotalSize(WebViewDatabase.java:735)
at android.webkit.CacheManager.trimCacheIfNeeded(CacheManager.java:557)
at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: I'm having the same error and no clue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This causes when you're using ads but sometimes webviewdb is null, to fix this:

```
WebViewDatabase webViewDB = WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this);  
if (webViewDB == null) {  
  View adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);  
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
  }
}
```

This issue was fixed in the Android OS 2.3+, so until this OS version will catch you have to disable the ads to people with this problem.